# Identify flash files via oembed

Tags: php, oembed

How can I identify an flash file via oembed? One problem is that there is no specific type in ombed to identify flash files or animations in general. Another problem is that provider return the wrong type for flashes.

For example, when I make a request to deviantART for a flash it the type I get is "photo". The property `url` also refers to an image (png).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

AFAIK there is no way to identify flash files via oembed. Furthermore flash is proprietary and  therefore it's unlikly to be added to the oembed standard.

The only solution I had come up so far is to use seperat logic for given sites. For example for deviantART the returned category can be used (which starts with "Flash" in that case).